# Seg fault error in C

Tags: c, timer, segmentation-fault, signals, void-pointers

Getting seg-fault when I run this code. I commented where I'm getting the seg-fault (in `handler()` function). I'm not sure, may be I'm wrapping data twice that's why or what's the problem? It's printing correctly till "start_timer" method.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct _data{
    char *name;
}data;  

struct timer_list{
   void* timer_data;
   unsigned long expires;
   void (*function)(sigval_t);
};

volatile long int second = 0;  

void handler(sigval_t val)
{
    data *data_handler =  val.sival_ptr;
    printf("Handler: address of data: %p\n", data_handler);
    printf("Handler: address of &data_handler->name: %p\n", &data_handler->name);
    printf("Handler entered with value :%s\n", data_handler->name); `**//**SEG-FAULT HERE****` 
}  

void timer_handler(union sigval val)
{
    printf(" ----- Seconds: %ld\n", ++second);
}  

/* start timer with all we got as data is timer */
void start_timer(struct timer_list *timer)
{
    printf("\nStart_timer...: Timer->data address: %p\n", timer->timer_data);
    data *data_handler = timer->timer_data;
    printf("Start_timer...: entered with value :%s\n", data_handler->name);
    int Ret;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init( &attr );
    //pthread_t tid;

    struct sched_param parm;
    parm.sched_priority = 255;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &parm);

    struct sigevent sig;
    sigval_t val;
    val.sival_ptr = timer->timer_data;
    sig.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    sig.sigev_notify_function = timer->function;
//  sig.sigev_value.sival_int = val;
    sig.sigev_value = val;
    sig.sigev_notify_attributes = &attr;

    data *data_handler1 = (data *)val.sival_ptr;
    printf("From sigval...: handler_data address: %p\n", data_handler1);
    printf("From sigval...: handler_data->name address: %p\n", &data_handler1->name);
    printf("From sigval...: Handler entered with value :%s\n", data_handler1->name);

//create a new timer.
    timer_t timerid;
    Ret = timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sig, &timerid);
    if (Ret == 0)
    {
        struct itimerspec in, out;
        in.it_value.tv_sec = timer->expires;
        in.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
        in.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        in.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    timer_settime(timerid, 0, &in, &out);

    }  
}  

/* Start_timer_on: wrapping up data into one timer structure, and starting timer */
void start_timer_on(data timer_data, unsigned long expires)
{
    struct timer_list *timer = (struct timer_list *)malloc(sizeof(struct timer_list)); //Problem was here ... forgot to use malloc 
    timer->timer_data = &timer_data;
    printf("\nTimer->data address: %p\n", &timer_data);
    timer->function = handler;
    timer->expires = expires;
    start_timer(timer);
}  

/* Main */
void main()
{
    data handler_data1 = {"Handler Data 1"};
    //data handler_data2 = {"Handler Data 2"};
    //void *data1 = &handler_data1;
    //void *data2 = &handler_data2;

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init( &attr );

    struct sched_param parm;
    parm.sched_priority = 255;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &parm);

    struct sigevent sig;
    sig.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    sig.sigev_notify_function = timer_handler;
    sig.sigev_notify_attributes = &attr;

//create a new timer - clock.
    timer_t timerid;
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sig, &timerid);


    struct itimerspec in, out;
    in.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    in.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    in.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    in.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    printf("*** *** *** Main clock starts *** *** ***\n");
    timer_settime(timerid, 0, &in, &out);
    printf("***** Start timer for data1 for 2 sec *****\n");
    start_timer_on(handler_data1, 2);
//    printf("***** Start timer for data1 for 5 sec  *****\n");
//    start_timer(data2, 5);     

    sleep(20);
}
```

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger, and see if the memory accesses are doing what you think they should be.

Comment: Segmentation Fault means that you're trying to access a memory element  or saving into it that's out of bound, check the assigning lines in your code, make sure that you provided the right size for your containers and check if your saving into a pointer a value that's not a valid memory address.

Comment: @andrewcooke yahh it is .... and then realized its a stupid mistake !! :(

Answer (score 2):

This might be the problem. In the code below, `timer_data` is local to function `start_timer_on`. The object is destroyed as soon as the function exits. So, when accessing the `name` in handler, it will segfault.

```
void start_timer_on(data timer_data, unsigned long expires)
{
    struct timer_list *timer;
    timer->timer_data = &timer_data;
    printf("\nTimer->data address: %p\n", &timer_data);
    timer->function = handler;
    timer->expires = expires;
    start_timer(timer);
}
```

You should use `void start_timer_on(data *timer_data, unsigned long expires)`, so that the data is not freed until `main` exits.

Comment: A related problem: the variable `timer` is never initialized.  De-referencing it using the `->` operator isn't allowed.

Comment: @deebee hadler is getting data through sigval_t ... if you don't know timer - create_timer and timer_settimer , should nt reply.

Comment: @all ,I edited question, problem was malloc ... in start_timer_on, I haven't used malloc before

Comment: @DharaDarji I know how handler is getting the data. I based my answer on your claim of where segfault is happening.